# How can I downcast a trait to a concrete type when the type contains a lifetime?

Tags: rust

Downcast_rs (and other libraries) break when the struct I want to downcast to contains a lifetime. For example:

```rs
use downcast_rs::{Downcast, impl_downcast};


trait Trait: Downcast{

}
impl_downcast!(Trait);
struct A<'a>{
    i:&'a i32
}
impl<'a> Trait for A<'a>{}
fn main() {
    let i = 15;
    let a: Box<dyn Trait> = Box::new(A{i: &i});
    if let Some(test) = a.downcast_ref::<A>(){
        println!("{}",test.i);
    }
}
```

This code results in multiple errors, mainly:

```rs
error[E0478]: lifetime bound not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:11:10
   |
11 | impl<'a> Trait for A<'a>{}
   |          ^^^^^
   |
note: lifetime parameter instantiated with the lifetime `'a` as defined here
  --> src/main.rs:11:6
   |
11 | impl<'a> Trait for A<'a>{}
   |      ^^
   = note: but lifetime parameter must outlive the static lifetime
```

How should I (or shouldn't I) go about implementing downcasting for lifetimes or what should I do instead? Also I am not replacing downcasting with enums. That isn't an option.

Comment: You cannot (except for `'static`)

Comment: what sort of alternatives would you suggest?

Comment: Re-evaluate your design. Downcasting is a code smell: you should assess *why* your are downcasting and try to move that behavior into a trait method instead. If that doesn't work then you'd have to change your types to avoid lifetimes by taking ownership, using shared ownership, or something else.

Comment: I am making something similar to a physics engine where there is a trait called Object, and I want to check if the Object is a specific kind and then do specific behavior for that object. I want it to be extendable (in ways that enums don't easily support). I am not sure what a more elegant way to do this is? What do you suggest in a situation like this. Thank you kmdreko for helping me here.

Comment: Please re-read my comment; I was precise with my wording by providing two options (one is preferable over the other). 1) try to move that behavior into a trait method instead or 2) change your types to avoid lifetimes. Just knowing its a physics engine with objects doesn't really change that.

Comment: To extend kmdreko's comment, if some Objects need special handling then the trait itself should indicate that possibility. A physics example could be that rigid bodies have an orientation, while particles don't; as such, you might give Object a method `fn orientation(&self) -> Option<Quaternion>` to indicate that specialization.

Comment: You might also consider building the engine around an entity-component-system model, where the behavior of a particular object is determined by what things (components) it is composed of, rather than what specific type it has.